# How to update value after modifying the current value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have more than 5000 entries having incorrect values. In users table, numbers column has below value

```
225+2250500000000
```

I want to remove 225 and keep and rest number. So the numbers column should have below

```
+2250500000000
```

How can I do that with MySQL query?

Comment: Does all incorrect values matches the pattern `.+\+\d+`?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
set yourField = REPLACE(yourField,'225+','+')
WHERE yourField LIKE '225+%';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did with substr. Is it okay to do with substr()?

Comment: @Ayaz Ali Shah n- but only substr() will remove it in all rows not only in rows with wrong settings and if you execute more than one time it destroys all entrys

Comment: I tested with another table to verify if it does not affect or replace another number with the current.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In case your data are not consistent like:

```
+--------------------+
|      numbers       |
+--------------------+
| 225+2250500000000  |
| 2250+2250500000000 |
| 22+2250500000000   |
| +2250500000000     |
+--------------------+
```

Then I suggest `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the numbers at the end of `+` and `CONCAT()` to add the `+` back:

```
SELECT numbers,
       CONCAT('+',SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers,'+',-1))
 FROM test;

+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|      numbers       |  CONCAT('+',SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers,'+',-1)) |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 225+2250500000000  |   +2250500000000                             |
| 2250+2250500000000 |   +2250500000000                             |
| 22+2250500000000   |   +2250500000000                             |
| +2250500000000     |   +2250500000000                             |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

with `UPDATE`, maybe add a `WHERE` if necessary:

```
UPDATE test 
   SET numbers=CONCAT('+',SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers,'+',-1))
WHERE numbers LIKE '%+%';
```

Here's another method; use `LOCATE` to find the location of '+', then use `SUBSTRING()` from that position:

```
SELECT numbers,
       SUBSTRING(numbers, LOCATE('+',numbers))
 FROM test
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried and done successfully, below is the query

```
UPDATE `users`
SET `numbers` = SUBSTR(numbers, 4, 18)
```